# NoSQL and unbounded many-to-many relationships

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

(I know similar questions have been asked, but I haven't found a solid answer)

In NoSQL (MongoDB) how do I best model unbounded many-to-many relationships? An example; If I have a `user` and a `post`. `users` can potentially have unlimited posts and `posts` can have unlimited likes.

**Embedding**
Does not seems like a viable solution as the document sizes will grow too large.

**Junction/association table**
Seems like a viable solution - But I keep reading that NoSQL advices against using junction tables.

Am I missing a third option or is junction tables a solid solution in this case?

Comment: The `like` is usually just a flag and maybe a user-id. I don't see any problem to embed it in the document unless you expect a million likes. For `users` and `posts` it should be a valid option to use separate collections.

Comment: The `users` and `posts` was just an example. I do expect several thousands of references both ways.